# SP07 - Disable Inherit from parent and give per for group

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, permissions

I have a **aspx page** in my library. I want to disable inherit from parent and give permission on only one group.

I click on page in library --> Manage permissions --> Click on Actions.... What are other steps to solve this solution ?

[image]

I want to give permissions only for Group Human Resources for this document. How to do this ??

Comment: According to your screenshot, the document does not inherit permissions.  All you have to do now is click the checkbox next to the groups you want to remove, and select `Remove User Permissions` from the Actions dropdown.